# Method not found: GenericChart when using FSharp.Charting from powershell cmdlet

Tags: powershell, f#, powershell-cmdlet, missingmethodexception

I am trying to use the FSharp charting library from a powershell cmdlet (also written in F#) but I get a MissingMethodException for GenericChart.

The sample of the charting code:

```
open FSharp.Charting
let testchart() =
    let foo = DataAccessLayer.GetTestData()
    Chart.Line(foo) |> Chart.Show
```

The testchart function is called from the ProcessRecord() method on the PSCmdlet derived class.
Both the charting and cmdlet code are in the same solution, though different projects.  The solution compiles without error.  The charting code runs in interactive without error.  But when I try to execute the powershell cmdlet I get the missing method exception.
This happens when using VS2013 and VS2015.

According to documentation GenericChart should be in the FSharp.Charting.dll.  I confirmed that the dll is in the same directory as the powershell module code.

Again, in VS all the intellisense works, everything compiles and works in interactive.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Missing method exception is a common problem answered regularly here on the F# tag. It is so popular it has its own [tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/missingmethodexception).Did you search previous post? If so what did you try anything beyond ensuring it works with F# Interactive but not `cmdlet`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why am I getting a MissingMethodException when calling F# code from PowerShell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33696325/why-am-i-getting-a-missingmethodexception-when-calling-f-code-from-powershell)

Comment: @Coder, Previous post was on calling a function directly from powershell (i.e. calling f# from powershell code)  I am calling F# from F# code hosted in powershell environment.  I didn't think it was the same, though maybe it has the same cause?

Comment: Did you search the other tags for a possible solution? Also there are a few tags related to cmdlet: [cmdlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmdlet), [cmdlets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmdlets) and [pscmdlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pscmdlet) which might have the answer.

Comment: I don't use `cmdlet` so I was not sure and that is why I only put possible in the comment and did not mark it as a duplicate. It is mostly there to help others more knowledgeable find it and then decide if it is a duplicate. Thanks for the feedback, should help others.

Comment: No worries, I did search the other tags, most seem to be about dll versioning. The previous question on versioning in powershell had as an answer "fiddle with it till you get it to work or give up".  I appreciate the practicality of that but it is less than satisfying :)  I am beginning to believe that I have a versioning issue but I don't know why PS isn't using the DLLs provided in the module directory?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to having an obsolete copy of the Libraries.  Rebuild from scratch using the latest F# libraries and it will clear.

I had exactly the same error message and doing so fixed it.